# Best practice of angular code structuring

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The problem is I don't know if it's viable in Angular.JS to place every separate code entity (controller, model, service etc) in a separate .js file. I'm trying to implement my solution this way at the moment, but it just doesn't feel right.

Example:

**step.js content (model prototype):**

```
(function() {
    var moduleStep = angular.module('step', []);
    moduleStep.config(function() {
        var defaults = {
            title: "",
            enabled: true,
            active: false,
            visited: false,
            viewUrl: "/clientTemplates/notification/step1.html",
            model: {}
        };

        /**
         * @param {string} title
         * @param {string} viewUrl
         * @param {object} model   [optional]
         * @constructor
         */
        moduleStep.Step = function(title, viewUrl, model) {
            _.extend(this, defaults);
            this.title = title;
            this.viewUrl = viewUrl;
            _.isUndefined(model) && (this.model = model);
        };
        var prot = moduleStep.Step.prototype;

        /**
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        prot.isValid = function () {
            return true;
        }
    });
}());
```

**masterController.js content (controller):**

```
(function() {
    var moduleController = angular.module('masterController', [
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'step',
        'config'
    ]);

    moduleController.config(function() {
            var Step = angular.module('step').Step;

            /**
             * @type {Array}
             */
            $scope.steps = [
                new Step("step 1", "/clientTemplates/notification/step1.html"),
                new Step("step 2", "/clientTemplates/notification/step2.html", {test2: 2}),
                new Step("step 3", "/clientTemplates/notification/step3.html", {test: 1})
            ];
        };
        controller.$inject = ['$scope'];

        moduleController.masterController = controller;
        console.log(moduleController.masterController);
    });
}());
```

**setupMaster.js (application module)**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('setupMaster', [
//    'ngRoute',
        //controllers
        'masterController',
        'config'
    ]);


    /**
     * Конфигурационная функция для провайдеров служб приложения
     */
    app.config(['$controllerProvider', '$httpProvider', function($controllerProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $controllerProvider.register('MasterController', angular.module('masterController').masterController);
    }]);
}());
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

In the "recommended setup" block it is written that 4 large modules should be used for services, directives, filters and the application layer. What about controllers or models factories/prototypes?

Maybe it's just me being stupid or not compatible with Angular's paradigm, but module and injectors systems in Angular seem a bit over-engineered and counter-intuitive. Though i really like Angular's 2-way data binding and dirty-checking instead of callbacks.

Comment: Google "angular seed" and look around for examples.

Comment: @Stewie, thanks, but angular seed doesn't address real problems possible in large applications. 

There 4 JS-files are used, much like it's recommended in the "Module" manual I linked to in my question. Is it alright, if there are only 4 source files for a LOT of entities? Isn't it dirty?

Comment: Well, I was not referring to [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) specifically, but to other other seeds that can be found as well. There's plenty.

Comment: Use a Yeoman generator, I like https://npmjs.org/package/generator-cg-angular. It really helps you with sorting out file structure etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs code/naming conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802798/angularjs-code-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find best practices and justifications over reasons. In addition to reading angular docs, other article.. I found [JohnPapa's](http://www.johnpapa.net/) description and in-depth explanation gives a little more insight of why's and why-not's, do's and don'ts. [Read it here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#modularity)

Like others suggested, do checkout angular-seed and other ng-generators etc. Eventually, it is where you are comfortable with the right practices which evolves over time.

No rights or wrongs because they all have valid points. ie. testability, dependency injection, minification, optimization.. etc.

Just to share..

Answer (score 0):

Im working with w11k Fabs wich is a basic grunt setup with stuff like livereload/jshint/sass,less/testing/ngannotate...

The setup is view/route-orientated. Means the views/route are in a hierarchic foulder structure. For every view/route a new module and ctrl file. fabs handles to link them in your index file. since service are used in several views they are stored in a seperate folder.

if you "grunt dist" your project everything is minified into 1 file.

try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabs